# Updated to 14.04.1 can't launch desktop, black screen with cross cursor

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Updated my HP Proliant N54L  from 13.04 to 14.04.1, everything went smoothly until the reboot, as it started to load up the desktop it displayed this screen:

[image]

I can access terminal from that screen, I tried the following but it didn't work

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the X11 server is starting but the gnome-session is not.  If the gnome-session does not start, then Compiz and Unity will not be started either.

Try looking in ~/.cache/upstart/gnome-session-Unity.log to see if there are any obvious errors.

Comment: Tried to, says file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Xorg, Xserver and - most important - all Xserver/Xorg **video drivers**. Here's the shell terminal supercommand:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-common xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid libva1 --reinstall -y && sudo telinit 6
```

- If the make (manufacturer) of your video device (a.k.a. GPU, which stands for Graphics Processing Unit) is **Nvidia**, add **libvdpau1** to the above supercommand. The resulting supercommand will then be:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get install libvdpau1 xorg xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-common xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid libva1 --reinstall -y && sudo telinit 6
  ```
- If the make (manufacturer) of your GPU is **AMD**, add **xvba-va-driver** to the above supercommand. The resulting supercommand will then be:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get check && sudo apt-get install xvba-va-driver xorg xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-common xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid libva1 --reinstall -y && sudo telinit 6
  ```

If your computer's GPU uses shared memory from your computer's RAM, then check the manufacturer of your board's chipset. E.g.: if it has an AMD chipset, then install **xvba-va-driver** (most HP microservers use AMD chipset).

Your system will be restarted after the full reinstall by the above supercommand. The correct video modules will then be loaded and the GUI (Graphical User Interface) will work properly.